# How to handle force close event in IONIC - 3

Tags: cordova, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

I want to run some code when application is cleared from background . I know when when application get clear using swipe up from application list the cordova `pause` event get called like below code i have written the code inside `pause` method but its not getting called.

Here is my code..

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
if (platform.is('cordova')) {
//Subscribe on pause
        this.platform.pause.subscribe(async() => {

           await this.save();//this method is not executing i am storing the values in local storage here.
 });

        this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
}

        });
      }
    });
```

Any idea what is the best way to store data when application force to close or clear from the application list

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to handle a forced close in your app. If the user wants to kill it, he will be able to and you won't notice.

The only workaround I have found is to use the background mode with this [plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode) (look for the one that matches your Ionic version).

That way your are going to be able to keep doing tasks in the background, and you can store the data you need. In addition to this, you can handle the back button event also.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response what i understand it enable and disable the background operation if the application is in background does it work if we clear the app from background i mean does it execute the codes

Comment: The user can always kill your app in the background too, but you are going to have time to store your data. The best thing to do anyways is to storing your data while you are getting it. So if the users kills the app, you already have it stored.
Another aproach can be handle when the app is in background (not necessarily killed) and store your data there.

Comment: Yes i tried the second approach pause() method but if the user quickly removing the the code chuck inside the pause method is not executing